# Hexadecimal addition without using any decimal conversion techniques

Tags: java, string, hex

I'm using the `Scanner` class to get input from the console. 
I'm trying to get my input as integer(.nextInt()) but it does not accept any hexadecimal values. How can start my Program? How to take inputs as HexaDecimal Numbers and Process it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.nextInt(16)` but remember about `Integer.MAX` limit

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input hex number: ");
    int myDecNum = scan.nextInt(16);
    String myHexNum = Integer.toHexString(myDecNum);
    System.out.println("Output decimal number: " + myDecNum);
    System.out.println("Output hexadecimal number: " + myHexNum);
```

will produce this output:

```
Input hex number: a3
Output decimal number: 163
Output hexadecimal number: a3
```